# duplicate html forms to open jquery dialog boxes

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a couple of buttons where I want to bring up an html form in a jquery modal dialog:

```
<button class="add1">Add1</button>
<button class="add2">Add2</button>


<div id="form1">
<form id='AddForm1' name='' method='post' action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>'>
    <label for="Name">Name:&nbsp;</label>
    <input id="Name" name="camera_name" size="24" maxlength="36" value="Enter label for camera" onclick="this.select()" />
    <label for='Quality'>Quality:&nbsp;</label>
    <select id='Quality' name='quality'>
        <option value='HIGH' selected='selected'>High</option>
        <option value='MEDIUM'>Medium</option>
        <option value='LOW'>Low</option>
    </select>
    <label for='Status'>Status:&nbsp;</label>
    <select id='Status' name='status'>
        <option value='ENABLED' selected='selected'>On</option>
        <option value='DISABLED'>Off</option>
    </select>
    <label for='EmailNotice'>Email notice:&nbsp;</label>
    <select id='EmailNotice' name='email_notice'>
        <option value='ENABLED' selected='selected'>On</option>
        <option value='DISABLED'>Off</option>
    </select>
    <label for='Sensitivity'>Sensitivity:&nbsp;</label>
       <select id='Sensitivity' name='sensitivity'>
        <option value='HIGH'>High</option>
        <option value='AVERAGE' selected='selected'>Average</option>
        <option value='LOW'>Low</option>
    </select>
    <input type='hidden' name='type' value='TYPE1' />
    <button type='submit' class='submitme' name='add' value='Add'>Add</button>
    <button type='button' class='cancel_changes' name='cancel_changes' value='Cancel'>Cancel</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Now I have a second form that has common items like name, quality, status, and email notice but some things are different depending on the button they select.

```
<div id="form2">
<form id='AddForm2' name='' method='post' action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>'>
    <label for="Name">Name:&nbsp;</label>
    <input id="Name" name="camera_name" size="24" maxlength="36" value="Enter label for camera" onclick="this.select()" />
    <label for='Quality'>Quality:&nbsp;</label>
    <select id='Quality' name='quality'>
        <option value='HIGH' selected='selected'>High</option>
        <option value='MEDIUM'>Medium</option>
        <option value='LOW'>Low</option>
    </select>
    <label for='Status'>Status:&nbsp;</label>
    <select id='Status' name='status'>
        <option value='ENABLED' selected='selected'>On</option>
        <option value='DISABLED'>Off</option>
    </select>
    <label for='EmailNotice'>Email notice:&nbsp;</label>
    <select id='EmailNotice' name='email_notice'>
        <option value='ENABLED' selected='selected'>On</option>
        <option value='DISABLED'>Off</option>
    </select>
    <label for='UserName'>User name:&nbsp;</label>
       <input id='UserName' size='14' maxlength='16' name='add_user' value="Enter username" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter username') this.value='';" />
    <label for='Pass'>Password:&nbsp;</label>
    <input type='password' size='12' maxlength='16' id='Pass' name='add_pass' value='' />
        <label for='IP'>Enter IP:&nbsp;</label>
        <input id='IP' name='add_ip' size='10' value="Enter IP" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter IP') this.value='';" />
        <label for='Port'>Enter port:&nbsp;</label>
        <input id='Port' name='add_port' size='12' maxlength='6' value="Enter Port" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter Port') this.value='';" />
    <input type='hidden' name='type' value='TYPE2' />
    <button type='submit' class='submit' name='add' value='Add'>Add</button>
    <button type='button' class='cancel_changes' name='cancel_changes' value='Cancel'>Cancel</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Depending on the button they clicked it will open a jquery dialog.

```
var $dialog1 = $('#form1').dialog({
    modal:true,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable:false,
    width: 625
}); //init dialog

var $dialog2 = $('#form2').dialog({
    modal:true,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable:false,
    width: 625
}); //init dialog

//events
$('.add1').click(function(e) {
    $dialog1.dialog('open');
});

$('.add2').click(function(e) {
    $dialog1.dialog('open');
});

$(".cancel_changes").click(function() {
    $dialog1.dialog('close');
    $dialog2.dialog('close');
});

$(".submit_camera").click(function() {
    $("#AddForm1").validate({
    //all validation stuff
});
```

Finally to my question, this opens up dialogs with the appropriate forms but I started duplicating lots of stuff here. Once I got to the validation stuff in the submit it starts to get crazy the amount of duplication. My forms need to be cleaned up because I have ids with the same name. I'm thinking that there has to be a better way than duplicating everything. Perhaps having only 1 form somehow?

Comment: You could just have one form with some elements hidden with CSS/JS as per the user's input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an options object for a plugin, you can also pass an existing object as a variable to the plugin, instead of duplicating the same object again in your code.

In the case of the forms, you can create one object that contains all the duplicate rules, then extend that object with rules specific to each form.

Although not a big savings in code in this instance, adding data attributes to elements can help cut down code as well. Generally it is better not to use unique classes for same style and use of elements like `add1, add2` vs `add_btn`. Then css selectors in code are much easier to aggregate numerous elements in one selector.

Using traverse techniques instead of worrying about ID's , and thus over complicatiing or duplicating code is extremely helpful

Simplistic html mod- common class and data attribute:

```
  <button class="add1 add_btn" data-form_num="1">Add1</button>
```

Some JS Simplifications that incorporate a variety of ways to streamline per notes above:

```
/* store dialog options for numerous dialogs*/
var dialogOpts={
    modal:true,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable:false,
    width: 625
}
/* combine selectors for dialogs - one common class would simplify further*/
$('#form1,#form2 ').dialog(dialogOpts); //init dialog


/* combine selectors by using common class*/
$('.add_btn').click(function(e) {
        /* use attributes to determine which to open */                      
    $('#form'+ $(this).data('form_num') ).dialog('open');
});



$(".cancel_changes").click(function() {
    /* tarverse rather than worry about specific ID's*/                             
    $(this).closest('form').parent().dialog('close');   
});


/*  rules for all forms */
var all_forms_rules={
    'camera_name': 'required',
    'email_notice': 'required'  
}

var form_1_rules={
    'sensitivity': 'required'   
}
/* extend form_1_rules by merging "rules" */
form_1_rules= $.extend({}, form_1_rules,all_forms_rules)

$(".submit_camera").click(function() {
    $("#AddForm1").validate({
            /* pass rules object as variable */             
          rules: form_1_rules

    })
});
```